# java xpath not valid xpath error

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The following errors I am getting when trying the run my code

```
The string '//div[@data-selenium='raisedAmount']/a']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

The xpath shown above is there any problem with it. Please help.
I am using Java Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems OK except for an unbalanced closing square bracket. Perhaps this should work:

```
//div[@data-selenium='raisedAmount']/a
```